# Java Generics incompatible types for the exact same class

Tags: java, generics

Here is an example of my Java code:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    private static class Something<T>{
        public void fun(Class<T> someClass){
            someClass.cast(null);
        }
    }
    private interface Hello{}

    public static void some(Something<? extends Hello> mySomething, Class<? extends Hello> myClass){
        mySomething.fun(myClass);
    }
}
```

And I'm getting a weird error at the `mySomething.fun(myClass)` line:

```
Required type: Class<? extends com.company.Main.Hello>
Provided: Class<? extends com.company.Main.Hello>
```

Which are the exact same type...

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't see any line marked with "Here!" (wink, wink) And you didn't post `main` method.

Comment: @Amongalen You don't really need a main method for compile time errors to show up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the question mark in the "required" and "provided" can be different. Suppose I have two implementations of `Hello`: `Hello1` and `Hello2`. I could call:

```java
some(new Something<Hello2>(), Hello1.class);
```

That fulfills the contract of `some`, but you don't want to be able to call `new Something<Hello2>().someClass(Hello1.class)`.

I believe you need to express the constraint *once*, by making `some` generic:

```java
public static <T extends Hello> void some(Something<T> mySomething, Class<T> myClass)
```

Now the two parameters are appropriately related, so the call to `fun` is valid.

Answer (score 3):

`Class<? extends com.company.Main.Hello>` is a `Class` whose type parameter is `Hello` or some class that extends `Hello`.

Therefore two  unrelated `Class<? extends com.company.Main.Hello>` might represent two different sub-classes of `Hello`.

For example, suppose you passed to your `some(Something<? extends Hello> mySomething, Class<? extends Hello> myClass)` method a `Something<Hello1>` and a `Class<Hello2>`. Both `Hello1` and `Hello2` are sub-classes of `Hello`, but you can't pass a `Class<Hello2>` argument to the `fun()` method of `Something<Hello1>` (which requires a `Class<Hello1>`).

Answer (score 3):

`<? extends MyClass>` (in the first parameter) is not guaranteed to be the compatible to `<? extends MyClass>` (in the second parameter).

If the types were the same, for example:

```
public static <T> void some(Something<T> mySomething, Class<T> myClass) {
    mySomething.fun(myClass);
}
```

then compilation passes just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your `some()` definition to:

```
public static <T extends Hello> void some(Something<T> mySomething, Class<T> myClass) {
    mySomething.fun(myClass);
}
```

This is because in your `Something` class, the type `T` is used in the `fun` declaration in a way that the actual type of `T` must exactly be the same.

But in your `some` method, `? extends Hello` can be different classes. `Hello` can have multiple child classes.